# How to target all first childs on menus

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I simply want to target all first Li elements in my `.sub-menu` class and apply span element (caret).I achieved it,but not what i wanted,the caret class appeared on all li elements from sub-menu,i tried alot combinations of scripts and nothing works.If i use `.first()`it appear only on li elements in sub menus that have other than one childrens.So if you have 1 li element to drop,it won't appear on it.. Sorry for that brainstorm i hope you understand me.[This](http://prntscr.com/d9waig) is how mu menu looks like right now.With this code:

```js
$('.menu-new ul li:has(sub-menu)')
$('ul.sub-menu').parent('li').append('<span class=pc-caret></span');
```

```html
<div class="menu-new">
  <nav class="menu" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu ul">
       <span class="pc-caret"></span>
         <?php wp_nav_menu(array (
           'theme_location'=> 'new-menu',
   'container' => '', 
   'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
                                      )); ?>
                                   </ul>
                                 </nav>
                              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```js
/*
$('ul.sub-menu').each(function(i, elmt){
  $('li:eq(0)', elmt).append('<span class="pc-caret">span</span>');
});
*/

//$('ul.sub-menu').eq(0).prepend('<span class="pc-caret">span</span>');

$('ul.sub-menu').each(function(i, elmt){
  $(elmt).prepend('<span class="pc-caret">span</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>item 11</li>
  <li>item 21</li>
  <li>item 31</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>item 12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works,but it is same as mine in the start http://prntscr.com/d9wlxl I want caret to show only on upper element as it is now,and i want to remove This:http://prntscr.com/d9wmum

Comment: What do you mean with "upper element"? I think my example does exactly what you described and asked for: Append a span to every first li of every .sub-menu. If that's not what you want describe it more clearly please. Could it be that you don't want to append the span to the first li in every ul.sub-menu but as first element of the ul.sub-menu?

Comment: Thats what i wanted,but look at the picture,it is appearing on every Li elements.

Comment: I updated the example. If I got you right than it's now what you want ...

Comment: Yap mate,I am sorry for disturbing you 10 times,its cool now,but appear only on my first sub menu class ,on second there isn't any caret,here is my blog page,go check under test2 there isn't any caret class.
www.shreddingnation.com

Comment: You really make it hard to help you. So you want EVERY ul.sub-menu to have a span as first element and than the li elements? Edited the example once again. ope it's now what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for answers and time mate,its still not that what i wanted but i will achieve it with your ideas.Will mark this as answer,because i bet it will help somebody else.Thanks ! <3

Comment: Update:After many many many tries like 7 hours i still am not happy with the result,but its better than the beginning,i used your code and edited just the selection in front,and removed "span" between span class.It is good,but i have 1 more problem,how to remove that:http://prntscr.com/da0pq2 I don't want caret to appear on every li item in .sub menu,but only on first.

Comment: You say there're mor carets than you want. Then I ask where do they come from? Can't be from the code I gave you. Do you use some kind of library/template for the menu bar where they appear by default?

Comment: I am working on wordpress,carets cannot be presented as div's by default here.So no don't use any kind of library/template.Thats why  I am confused too xD

Comment: Well, the only option I see to help you some more is that you post the HTML in the status BEFORE you try to remove/add the span elements. And possibly the HTML you like to have afterwards. Then I might see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS for this, no need for jQuery.

```
ul.sub-menu li:first-child{
  /* Insert your Caret Styles here, instead of the span*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you should find the first li of your sub-menu and check if its first?
 use :eq(n) where n is your index. Index starts with 0.

```
 //as you have more than one ul with sub-menu class this should work for you
 $('ul.sub-menu').each(function(){

         $(this).find('li'):eq(0).append('<span class=pc-caret></span');

 });
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what you want? also your entire html code

Comment: I want span element with class  "pc-caret" to show only on upper Li element in .sub-menu.
Here is example menu :http://pastebin.com/EHp3eG8h

Comment: @UmreteKurvi try now and accept my answer if that helped :)

Comment: @UmreteKurvi it seems you have more than one ul with same class. Try now with updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
var subclass = $('.menu-new ul li').attr('class');
if(subclass=='sub-menu'){
$(".sub-menu ul li:first-child").append('<span class=pc-caret></span');
}
```